# BigQuery DML on column partitioned tables with streaming buffer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

As far as I understand, UPDATEs and DELETEs [are working](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36383555) on partitioned tables with streaming buffer, if query is not touching any records in streaming buffer. Otherwise, the following error is reported:

```
UPDATE or DELETE statement over table project.dataset.table would affect rows in the streaming buffer, which is not supported
```

Issue is similar to discussed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43085896/update-or-delete-tables-with-streaming-buffer-in-bigquery), however it's about column partitioned tables, not about ingestion-time partitioned tables.

Problem is, that while ingestion-time partitioned have means to [ignore data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables#ingestion-time_partitioned_tables_95_unpartitioned_partition) in streaming buffer via conditions on _PARTITIONTIME, it's not available for column-partitioned tables. Are there any other approaches that would allow to ignore streaming buffer data in DML statements?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you can [only use Legacy SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-column-partitions#listing_partitions_in_partitioned_tables) to get information about the streaming buffer.

Get all data from the streaming buffer like this:

```
#legacySQL
select MIN(partitioned_tstamp) AS min_tstamp
       , MAX(partitioned_tstamp) AS max_tstamp
       , COUNT(1) AS lines
FROM [my_dataset_id.mystreaming_data_table$__UNPARTITIONED__]
```

And get a summary of all partitions in the table like this:

```
#legacySQL
SELECT * 
FROM [my_dataset_id.mystreaming_data_table$__PARTITIONS_SUMMARY__]
```

I have no idea why this isn't supported yet in standard SQL or when it will be.

Comment: Problem is to delete data from such table - it does not seem possible to ignore records in streaming buffer.