# Delete data from BigQuery using console which was inserted using Streaming Insert

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have inserted some data into my table using Streaming Insert (insertAll) to test how the code works.
Now I want that data to be deleted from the table.

I used the following query:

```
DELETE FROM MY_DATASET.my_Table WHERE someColumn like 'XYZ%'
```

And got the following error:

```
UPDATE or DELETE statement over table MY_DATASET.my_Table would affect rows in the streaming buffer, which is not supported
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case waiting a couple of hours after last insert helped.

Another quicker solution was to filter by `time` column (if you have one in your table), so that BigQuery knows that your deletes won't affect streaming data:

```
time < TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
```

Take a look at [Update or Delete tables with streaming buffer in BigQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43085896/update-or-delete-tables-with-streaming-buffer-in-bigquery)

Comment: Yes. I came to know about the Stream Buffer later and waited for around 90mins. Then I was able to delete the dummy data.