# UPDATE or DELETE statement over table datasetName.table1 would affect rows in the streaming buffer

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to create a big query table and insert data into that table which was retrieved from postgres DB.
I have created java method to insert data into the big query table with streaming inserts.

But if there is any exception occurs, I need to delete the data in the same java method.

While deleting the data I am getting below error

```
com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException: UPDATE or DELETE statement over table datasetName.table1 would affect rows in the streaming buffer, which is not supported
```

When I tried to update/delete the data from table after sometime, I am able to do it without any error.

Comment: is the postgres db in Cloud SQL?

Comment: This is related to tables in Bigquery. Found the reason for the same in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43085896/update-or-delete-tables-with-streaming-buffer-in-bigquery?rq=2